# How to set all newly created Github projects board tasks to become issues by default

Tags: github, kanban, github-projects

Every new task I create in the Github projects board must be manually converted to an issue by me. I couldn't find any setting for what seems a most obvious thing, so is there any method of making that happen? The following screenshot is what I want to avoid.

TL;DR I want all tasks to become issues by default.

[image: Screenshot]